# Add missing dates into TimeSeries DataFrame with 'NaN' values for existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a DataFrame object representing a time series indexed in minute resolution. There are segments in which there are no entries, which have been identified as follows:

```
missing = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='1min').difference(df.index)
```

Doing a quick print of this results in the following output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-11 03:41:00', '2021-02-11 03:42:00',
           '2021-02-11 03:43:00', '2021-02-11 03:44:00',
           '2021-02-11 03:45:00', '2021-02-11 03:46:00',
           '2021-02-11 03:47:00', '2021-02-11 03:48:00',
           '2021-02-11 03:49:00', '2021-02-11 03:50:00',
           ...
           '2021-09-29 08:50:00', '2021-09-29 08:51:00',
           '2021-09-29 08:52:00', '2021-09-29 08:53:00',
           '2021-09-29 08:54:00', '2021-09-29 08:55:00',
           '2021-09-29 08:56:00', '2021-09-29 08:57:00',
           '2021-09-29 08:58:00', '2021-09-29 08:59:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=5057, freq=None)
```

My question is how to insert each of these values as a new row into the initial DataFrame object with `NaN` values for all columns existing in that initial dataframe as such:

| date | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31 23:59:00 | 3675.10 | 3678.63 | 3675.09 | 3676.23 |
| 2021-12-31 23:58:00 | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 2021-12-31 23:57:00 | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 2021-12-31 23:56:00 | 3676.79 | 3678.54 | 3676.32 | 3676.94 |
| 2021-12-31 23:55:00 | 3679.36 | 3679.36 | 3676.28 | 3676.65 |

Where, in this contrived example, the dates `2021-12-31 23:58:00` and `2021-12-31 23:57:00` would have been identified via the `date_range` function before and then inserted with `NaN` values into the initial DataFrame. In this case, I am not interested in interpolating between surrounding values.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your input dataframe?

Comment: have you looked at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: @Umar.H The input DataFrame is essentially the same as that in the last code block, just sans the rows with `NaN` values.

Comment: @programmar I am only vaguely familiar with the `resample` function -- I use it to turn n-periods into n/m periods often but am not fluent enough to know how to apply it in this case. Suggestions?

Comment: please have a chance to read [mcve] and [ask] you need to provide a representative sample of your input and output dataframes.

Comment: `new_df = df.merge(missing , how="outer")` check this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)!

```
df.resample('1T').fillna(method=None)
```

*Note: '1T' stands for 1 minute*

And here some code that works, recreating the data frame from your sample data. But please next time, provide this yourself. You will get better and faster answers!

```
import pandas
from io import StringIO


s = """date  a  b  c  d
2021-12-31 23:59:00  3675.10  3678.63  3675.09  3676.23
2021-12-31 23:56:00  3676.79  3678.54  3676.32  3676.94
2021-12-31 23:55:00  3679.36  3679.36  3676.28  3676.65"""


csvStringIO = StringIO(s)

df = pandas.read_csv(csvStringIO,  sep='  ', index_col='date')
df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.sort_index()

df.resample('1T').fillna(method=None)
```

Output:

```
                           a        b        c        d
date                                                   
2021-12-31 23:55:00  3679.36  3679.36  3676.28  3676.65
2021-12-31 23:56:00  3676.79  3678.54  3676.32  3676.94
2021-12-31 23:57:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2021-12-31 23:58:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2021-12-31 23:59:00  3675.10  3678.63  3675.09  3676.23
```

*Edit: Your index is unsorted. I had to add the line with `index_sort()`. Keep that in mind.*

Comment: This works great! The only issue is that the resulting data is in reversed order -- any idea how to avoid that? It's no issue to simply use `.iloc[::-1]` on the resulting DataFrame, I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: I just fixed that. How is it now?